# sqldate time overflow in ASP.NET using VB.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, nhibernate, activerecord

I've been through a tough day facing this problem. In `ent` object, I have `DiinputTanggal` property as Date. In database, I have `DiinputTanggal` column as DateTime. When I try to insert the `ent` object into the database, I got the following error shown in the screenshot below. But when I debug, the property `DiinputTanggal` in `ent` object seems perfectly fine and nicely formatted. I have no idea where is my mistake.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your screenshot, it is probably the `TaggalAktif` property which is causing the overflow. .Net DateTimes default to `DateTime.MinValue` which cannot be represented in SQL `DateTime`.

You have several options

- Initialize the DateTime to a value supported by Sql DateTime (in the range indicated by the error)
- Change the `DateTime` to be nullable in both the class and database, (and ensure the property is initialized to null).
- Use another [Sql DataType](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) to store the data e.g. `DateTime2` or just `Date` if time isn't needed.

Comment: Actually, I don't give the value on `TanggalAktif` property, because `TanggalAktif` is nullable column. I don't get it why this is happen.

Comment: In addition to being nullable in the database, you will either need to make the class property `Nullable Of DateTime` as well, or have a custom mapping to map `DateTime.MinValue` to `DBNull`.

Comment: Yes indeed, I am declare `TanggalAktif` property in my model using ActiveRecord like this: `<[Property]()> Public Overridable Property TanggalAktif() As Date` Any wrong with this? If I commented this property, my code is work finely